# Extract conditional instructions using IDA python in ARM binaries

Tags: ida, idapython, arm, python

While using IDA Python for extract ARM instructions, I noticed that some instructions are not extracted completely. For example, conditional instructions such as `BCS` or `BCC` are printed as `B`. For analyzing, it is necessary we have the instructions completely.

Here's the code I used:

```
import idautils
import idc
import idaapi
for seg_ea in Segments():
 for head in Heads(seg_ea, SegEnd(seg_ea)):
  if isCode(GetFlags(head)):
   disasm= GetMnem(head)
```

Is there any way to correct this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem on *IDA 6.95* but it seems like this bug was fixed in *[IDA 7](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/7.0/index.shtml)* since it works for me just fine. The solution below will be relevant to IDA 6.95 though it would probably be valid to earlier versions of *IDA Pro*.

Let's start by describing the deadlock we're facing with:
The problematic function, `GetMnem`, is declared in `IDA 6.95\Python\idc.py:L2280` and looks like this:

```
def GetMnem(ea):
    """
    Get instruction mnemonics

    @param ea: linear address of instruction

    @return: "" - no instruction at the specified location

    @note: this function may not return exactly the same mnemonics
    as you see on the screen.
    """
    res = ida_ua.ua_mnem(ea)

    if not res:
        return ""
    else:
        return res
```

Pay attention to the following disclaimer in the function:

> @note: this function may not return exactly the same mnemonics as you see on the screen.

Seems like our problems fits the disclaimer -- we don't see the same mnemonics as we see on the screen.

As you can see, `GetMnem` is basically a wrapper to another function -- `ua_mnem` which is declared in `IDA 6.95\Python\ida_ua.py:L319`:

```
def ua_mnem(*args):
  """
  ua_mnem(ea) -> char const *
  """
  return _ida_ua.ua_mnem(*args)
```

Well, seems like `ua_mnem` is a wrapper to another function which is located in `IDA 6.95\python\lib\python2.7\lib-dynload\ida_64\_ida_ua.pyd`. A `pyd` file [is actually a *DLL* file](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll) and should not be easy-peasy to reverse. Therefore, we can't see, nor edit, the source code so we can't fix the problem.

Here comes the workaround: instead of using `GetMnem` you can simply mimic it by using `GetDisasm` and split the line to get only the instruction:

```
import idautils
import idc
import idaapi
for seg_ea in Segments():
 for head in Heads(seg_ea, SegEnd(seg_ea)):
  if isCode(GetFlags(head)):
    mnem = GetMnem(head)
    if (mnem[0]=='B'):
        mnem = GetDisasm(head).split()[0]
    print mnem
```

In this case we check whether the mnemonics is a [branch instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0231b/Chddgiff.html) (begins with "B") and if so, we use the mnemonics from `GetDisasm` and not from `GetMnem`. Of course you would need to test this solution better and maybe handle some specific cases.

Comment: `_ida_ua.ua_mnem` is just a direct wrapper of the underlying IDA API from `ida_ua.hpp` in the SDK.